Related to PDF of the sum and product of exponential random variable
In my research work, I came across the following situation that involves sum and product of exponential random variable as shown:
$P = X_1 + \beta_0^2 X_2X_3$ ---(1)
where $\beta_0^2$ is constant and $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are independent and identically distributed exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$.
My efforts: I know that the PDF of product of two exponential random variables is given as:
Let $Z$ = $X_2X_3$ then $f_{Z}(z) = 2\lambda^2 K_0(2\lambda \sqrt{z})$---(2)
However I am not getting how the PDF of product of two exponential random variables given in (2) is obtained.
And so I am not getting how to find the PDF of the equation (1).
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Regarding (2), see here

Thank u so much sir for your response....but the link u gave do not have derivation of eq.(2).

Can we say that it is not possible to find the PDF of equation (1) ?
